# Include JavaScript file inside a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include JavaScript file inside JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

I have two js files a.js and b.js i want to include a.js inside the javascript file b.js.

How to include this,    please help me?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Direct your eyes to the "Related" pane on the right side of this page. You'll find quite a lot of answers there.